# unsupervised text classification with php

Tags: php, text, classification

Are there any pre-made libraries for PHP that can be used to help with tasks involving unsupervised text classification <sup>[information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_classification#Automatic_document_classification)</sup>?

I've looked around the site at other questions, but I have been unable to find a similar problem.

I would like to learn how to implement an unsupervised classification system.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: There is nothing pre-rolled that I am aware of, you will need to read up on the common algorithms and implement them yourself. And err... good luck! :-P

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/gburtini/Learning-Library-for-PHP

Some general unsupervised algorithms already implemented here. Maybe it will be you useful for you.